# subset time series data in R

Tags: r, time-series

I got a time series data and I use `windown` to get the subset from 1201 until 1700. The data on the same row would be truncated or kept. How to get exactly time data I want?

```
Time Series:
Start = 1203 
End = 1499 
Frequency = 0.125 
      V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8
1203  88 121  50  95  74  76  88  97
1211 140  45 145  76 100  66  40  55
1219  74  21  81  78  55  97  76 123
1227  52  83  57  17  78  55  71  62
1235  88  17  78 142  97 128 221 195
1243 128 190  52  95  74  97 100 100
......
```

Comment: May you share more about the package you are using and if possible `dput` a sample of your data would help alot.

Comment: I didn't use any particular package; just use the basic R functions to create `ts` object

Answer (score 1):

You can use the column name to subset. Change "data" to your database name and the "column_name" to the column you want use as filter.

```
new_data <- data[data$column_name >= 1201 & data$column_name <= 1700, ]
```